# How does imperfect stripping affect Aligned Rank Transform ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric

I have tried using ART ANOVA (ARTool) recently for two-way analyses, but I keep getting the warning that ART may not be appropriate because "F values of ANOVAs on aligned responses not of interest are not all ~0". According to Wobbrock *et al.*, 2011 ([ARTool webpage with literature](http://depts.washington.edu/acelab/proj/art/index.html)), this should indicate imperfect stripping of the effects that are not the one being aligned for.

If I understood the code of the function "summary.art" correctly, the comparison is based on the function "all.equal", checking for equality with 0 with the default tolerance, which is sqrt(.Machine$double.eps). This is ca. 1.5*10-8.

So far, I didn't find any information on how tolerant ARTool really is to this and it seems that the threshold for getting the warning is super low. Does anyone know how far from 0 one can get before the results start getting unreliable? In what way do they become less reliable? Any information or pointer is highly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by stripping here?

Comment: I was referring to the effects being stripped out by aligning the data, as mentioned in the following quote from the "Ensuring correctness" section of Wobbrock et al., 2011 (http://faculty.washington.edu/wobbrock/pubs/chi-11.06.pdf): 

"[...] a full-factorial ANOVA performed on the aligned (not ranked) responses Y′ should show all effects stripped out (F=0.00, p=1.00) except for the effect for which the data were aligned."

Comment: I tried manually equalising sample sizes and then I get no warning, so unbalanced sample sizes could be the reason. I don't know how big of a problem it is though.